# vespa - How much time Vespa process generally take for Startup to rebuild mmap of attributes?

Tags: vespa

while writing search definitions for indexing as "attribute" - I read from http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/search-definitions.html that it keeps fields in memory. basic question is: in case of cluster restart this in-memory data is rebuild from the index?

how much time does Vespa take in case of cluster restart to rebuild the attribute in memory? (let say a node has 2TB of data and half of the fields are defined as "attribute" - roughly 1TB for mmap?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attribute data needs to be read from disk into memory at startup and the time it takes depends on:

- Pure size (e.g multi-valued strings versus a single byte field) and number of documents/values.
- attribute settings (fast-access,fast-search etc) which will require additional in-memory structures to be built on top of the raw attribute data

So the answer is really 'it depends'.

A vespa content node with mode=index has 4 main directories with data where the attribute data is stored separately from the index. The attribute directory contains snapshot-xx/*.dat files which is read into memory into a data structure (hence not using file backed mmap)

```
ls /opt/vespa/var/db/vespa/search/cluster.x/n0/documents/x/0.ready/
attribute  documentmetastore  index  summary
```